# TFS not clearing build agent folders after migration to TFS2010

Tags: build, compilation

I am having an issue with TFS. When we had TFS2008, the build machine was able to clear files from the Build Agent Folders before creating a new build. However, after the migration to TFS2010, the build machine cannot clear this folder and we are getting builds with old files that have been deleted from source control.

Is there any way to get this functionality back? We are currently working with the TFS2008 build scripts and the **UpgradeTemplate.xaml** in TFS2010.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only other post I found didn't have an answer. So instead, I reverted back to running a RMDIR command at the BeforeEndToEndIteration level of the build script.

`<Target Name="BeforeEndToEndIteration">
    <Exec WorkingDirectory="S:\src" Command="RMDIR /s /q &quot;S:\src\Sandbox_awdbu\&quot;"/>
   </Target>`

This command will delete the build agent folder before the Get Latest command is performed by the build service.

It's not a great solution but it works. This solution will work but I would suggest moving onto the template instead of keeping the old TFS2008 build scripts.

Comment: Congrats on finding a fix!  When you are able, please make sure to mark your answer as 'accepted' (using the green checkmark) so that other users will be able to learn from your success.  Cheers~

Comment: @AndrewKozak Will do, unfortunately I will have to wait until tomorrow. Hope this helps others though.

Answer (score 1):

In your TFS Build Definition, what is the "Clean Workspace" on the "Process" tab set to?

It has three options:

- All
- Outputs
- None

An explanation of each options (taken from TFS):

> Set to All to delete all existing outputs and sources and do a full
>   rebuild; Outputs to delete all existing outputs but get only those
>   source files that have changed since the last build (Incremental Get);
>   or None to leave existing outputs and sources in place and build any
>   changes incrementally.

You should set this to `All`, to ensure you are performing a clean build each time.

Comment: thanks for that. Unfortunately we are not running the Default Template, we are running these TFS2008 scripts with the Upgrade Template and in that template there is no "Clean Workspace" option. 

I tried adding that variable beforehand but I was unsuccessful.

Comment: Ah, I've never looked at the upgrade template, sorry.

Comment: no problem. Thanks for looking into it. I did come up with a ghettofabulous solution for it by using the RMDIR commande at the "BeforeEndToEndIteration" level. I will post that as my solution as well.